# Node Schedule running indefinitely

Tags: node.js

I am using node schedule to sent out emails on particular dates. The dates are fetched from the database. The mails get sent out continuously in a loop if I run the application. It seems that both the jobs run continously even though the time specified in date has been in past or any one of the job is called..

In case, I don't fetch the dates from database and provide explicitly it runs fine. Please help.

Also if the dates are mentioned explicitly like reminder1 = new Date(2019,2,19,11,20,0); in the getDate function the application run fine but if i mention the dates from database in getDate() function no action would be performed.

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const {
    poolPromise,
    sqlInstance
} = require('./database')
const mailer = require('../routes/initiateCertification');

const month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

const res1 = [];
let reminder = [];
let year1, year2, month1, month2, date1, date2;
let reminder1, reminder2;
let res3 = [];
let reminders;
exports.getDate = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const pool = await poolPromise
        const result = await pool.request().query("SELECT TOP 1 [Reminder1],[Reminder2] FROM [dbo].[InitiateCertification] ORDER BY [ID] DESC");
        res1.push(result.recordset);
        reminder = res1[0][0]['Reminder1'].toString().split(" ");
        for (let i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
            if (reminder[1] == month[i]) {
                month1 = Number(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        year1 = Number(reminder[3]);
        date1 = Number(reminder[2]);
        reminder1 = new Date(year1, month1, date1, 13, 30, 0);
        // If i work with below line it work and runs only once
        //reminder1 = new Date(2019, 2, 19, 12, 45, 0);
        console.log(reminder1.toString())
        reminder = res1[0][0]['Reminder2'].toString().split(" ");
        for (let i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
            if (reminder[1] == month[i]) {
                month2 = Number(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        year2 = Number(reminder[3]);
        date2 = Number(reminder[2]);
        console.log(year1, year2, date1, date2, month1, month2);
        reminder2 = new Date(year2, month2, date2, 16, 58, 0);
        console.log(reminder2)
        reminders = {
            'reminder1': reminder1,
            'reminder2': reminder2
        };
        console.log(reminders)

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
}

function getEmailId = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const pool = await poolPromise
        let result = await pool.request().query("SELECT [EmailId], [ManagerId] FROM [dbo].[EmployeeData]");
        let result2 = await pool.request().query("SELECT [EmailId] FROM [dbo].[CertificationForm]");
        let res1 = result.recordset;
        let res2 = result2.recordset;
        let flag = true;
        for (let i = 0; i < res1.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < res2.length; j++) {
                if (res1[i]['EmailId'] == res2[j]['EmailId']) {
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
            if (flag == true) {
                res3.push(res1[i]);
            }
            flag = true;
        }
        console.log(res1);
        console.log(res2);
        console.log(res3);
        //res.json(res3);
        sendMail1(res3);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        // res.status(500)
        // res.send(err.message)
    }
}

function sendMail1(res) {
    //...
}


console.log(year1);
// with these two lines its running continously.
reminder2 = new Date(year2, month2, date2, 17, 1, 55);
reminder1 = new Date(year1, month1, date1, 11, 20, 0)
let rem1 = schedule.scheduleJob(reminder1, function() {
    console.log("rem1");
    getEmailId();

});
let rem2 = schedule.scheduleJob(reminder2, function() {
    getEmailId();
    console.log(reminder2)
    console.log("rem2");

});


//app.js

app.listen(PORT, function() {

    scheduled.getDate();
    scheduled.rem2;
    scheduled.rem1;
    console.log('Node.js server is running on port ' + PORT);
});
```

Comment: What does `console.log(reminders)` output in the `getDate` function?

Comment: The getDate()function is executed only once and the logs are dates (correct). The mail get sent repeatedly.

Comment: What is the exact output?

Comment: reminderTue Mar 19 2019 22:39:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
2019 2019 19 19 2 2
2019-03-19T17:10:00.000Z
{ reminder1: 2019-03-19T17:09:00.000Z,
  reminder2: 2019-03-19T17:10:00.000Z }

Comment: post this the mails would start getting sent continously

Comment: The issue is related to getDate() i guess because if i explicitly mention the date and pass to the scheduler and place the statement just above getdate it works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is happening is that when you create the schedule jobs the value of the `reminder1` and `reminder2` variables is not what you expect.  When the `reminder1` and `reminder2` variables are created they are passed in the `year2`, `month2` and `date2` variables that are undefined at that time.  The code later assigns these values in the `getDate` function.  The `getDate` function needs to be called before the jobs are created.

Try this code :

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const {
    poolPromise,
    sqlInstance
} = require('./database')
const mailer = require('../routes/initiateCertification');

const month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

const res1 = [];
let reminder = [];
let year1, year2, month1, month2, date1, date2;
let reminder1, reminder2;
let res3 = [];
let reminders;
exports.getDate = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const pool = await poolPromise
        const result = await pool.request().query("SELECT TOP 1 [Reminder1],[Reminder2] FROM [dbo].[InitiateCertification] ORDER BY [ID] DESC");
        res1.push(result.recordset);
        reminder = res1[0][0]['Reminder1'].toString().split(" ");
        for (let i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
            if (reminder[1] == month[i]) {
                month1 = Number(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        year1 = Number(reminder[3]);
        date1 = Number(reminder[2]);
        reminder1 = new Date(year1, month1, date1, 13, 30, 0);
        // If i work with below line it work and runs only once
        //reminder1 = new Date(2019, 2, 19, 12, 45, 0);
        console.log(reminder1.toString())
        reminder = res1[0][0]['Reminder2'].toString().split(" ");
        for (let i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
            if (reminder[1] == month[i]) {
                month2 = Number(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        year2 = Number(reminder[3]);
        date2 = Number(reminder[2]);
        console.log(year1, year2, date1, date2, month1, month2);
        reminder2 = new Date(year2, month2, date2, 16, 58, 0);
        console.log(reminder2)
        reminders = {
            'reminder1': reminder1,
            'reminder2': reminder2
        };
        console.log(reminders)

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
}

function getEmailId = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const pool = await poolPromise
        let result = await pool.request().query("SELECT [EmailId], [ManagerId] FROM [dbo].[EmployeeData]");
        let result2 = await pool.request().query("SELECT [EmailId] FROM [dbo].[CertificationForm]");
        let res1 = result.recordset;
        let res2 = result2.recordset;
        let flag = true;
        for (let i = 0; i < res1.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < res2.length; j++) {
                if (res1[i]['EmailId'] == res2[j]['EmailId']) {
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
            if (flag == true) {
                res3.push(res1[i]);
            }
            flag = true;
        }
        console.log(res1);
        console.log(res2);
        console.log(res3);
        //res.json(res3);
        sendMail1(res3);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        // res.status(500)
        // res.send(err.message)
    }
}

function sendMail1(res) {
    //...
}


console.log(year1);

let rem1, rem2;
let createJobs = () => {

    // with these two lines its running continously.
    reminder2 = new Date(year2, month2, date2, 17, 1, 55);
    reminder1 = new Date(year1, month1, date1, 11, 20, 0)
    rem1 = schedule.scheduleJob(reminder1, function() {
        console.log("rem1");
        getEmailId();

    });
    rem2 = schedule.scheduleJob(reminder2, function() {
        getEmailId();
        console.log(reminder2)
        console.log("rem2");

    });
}
//app.js

app.listen(PORT, function() {

    scheduled.getDate();

    createJobs();

    scheduled.rem2;
    scheduled.rem1;
    console.log('Node.js server is running on port ' + PORT);
});
```

Comment: yeah i think the same i am calling  the getDate() when the server starts running how should I wait for the execution of getDate() to be over? Newbie here!!!

Comment: i tried putting the schedule method inside the getDate() but didn't work

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. I tried. But it is still running continuously. And also suppose rem1 should execute but it is executing both rem1 and rem2 continuously.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. It worked. I used async/await in app.js file for calling getDate
() and then called createJobs(). Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

The code posted by in the next answer along with async/await in app.js file worked for me.

```
let scheduler = async() => {
//   console.log("shdhd");
    await scheduled.getDate();
    scheduled.createJobs();
}


app.listen(PORT, function () {
    scheduler();
    console.log('Node.js server is running on port ' + PORT);
});
```